# How to call a function inside a separate cpp file through header to the main file?

Tags: c++, class, header

I am learing c++

All I want to know is I made a three file in code blocks using GCC compiler main.cpp printing.h printing.cpp

And I want to print the text in function "printer" in class "printingarea" in the file "printing.cpp" and want to prototype it in  "printing.h" and want to call in "main.cpp"

Comment: The code is awful. I'm not saying this to put you off, but rather to motivate you to learn C++ from a book. This shows a lack of **fundamental** (read again - **fundamental**) C++ knowledge, which you can't just pick up on the go, here and there.

Comment: +1 for you to start reading a c++ book. You lack fundamental understanding of the language.

Comment: Specifically, by fundamentals, @LuchianGrigore is referring to separating declarations into headers, and definitions into cpp files (generally).  I agree - a C++ primer is highly recommended.

Comment: Him doesn't even know how  to declare the scope of main...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore can you say which part of the code is awful . for reference see Adam s code. this is simplest code to explain about header.so that i can improve my code. and i am noob in C++

Comment: @LuchianGrigore please write it !!!

Comment: Did you already read the book? Which one?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore FYI i can't read books properly because i have a disorder of reading books. i can read things which are interactive. i learn 90% things from tutorial videos on youtube. So please tell me which part of the code is awful.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Please Write it !!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Claudios answer:

*printing.h*

```
class PrintingArea{
    public:
        void printer();
};
```

*printing.cpp*

```
#include "printing.h"
#include <iostream>

void PrintingArea::printer() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World !";
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "printing.h"

int main()
{
    PrintingArea pa;
    pa.printer();

    return 0;
}
```

As you see, you define the prototype of the class in the header, and the implementation of the methods in the cpp.

Comment: Why -1 on this answer?

Comment: who gave -1 for this answer please comment why ???

Comment: and adam in printing.cpp you are using std::cout because you are not using "using namespace std" am i right ?

Comment: Yes, `using namespace std` makes the namespace `std` used by default. Else you have to specify `std::` on members of the std namespace.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but that completely unecessary, Java-esque `new` in there is fingernails down my blackboard. Why not create `pa` on the stack, where it will be auto-destroyed when `main()` is left (via `return` or because `PrintingArea::printer()` threw an exception)? **Do not** call `new` *unless it is absolutely necessary*.

Comment: Creating objects on the heap instead the stack is *fundamental*. It may be unnecessary in this example but there is nothing bad about it. I'll edit it for the sake of simplicity though.

Comment: @AdamS: Disagree. It was 100% unnecessary in this example, gave a wrong impression of its necessity (unfortunately common among Java-to-C++ retrainers which then go on to complain about memory leaks, segfaults and bad performance of C++), and should be considered a "code smell" if outside a constructor or try-block. Twelve years in the trade, and I could count the number of *necessary* calls of `new` on three extremities. Four, tops. ;-) (No offense meant. I've seen *good* code using `new`, but the overwhelming majority was g++-compiled Java really.)

Comment: @DevSolar Maybe you are right, there can be more harm than good when using pointers carelessly, although I personally never had any problems with it. I'll try to avoid them if not necessary.

Comment: @AdamS program is giving error undefined reference to `PrintingArea::printer()'|

Comment: @Unknown: That's not a problem of Adam's code, but a problem of you calling the compiler wrongly. You have two translation units, `printing.cpp` and `main.cpp`. You have to compile them both, then link them together. Check your C++ textbook or favourite tutorial on how to do that; it's hardly material for a Q&A site like this.

Comment: @AdamS: Sorry for the hard wording, it was a long week. ;-)

Comment: @Unknown If you use a proper IDE, it does all the linking work for you. Try CodeBlocks, it's very lightweight.

Comment: @AdamS I am using CodeBlocks but the files was not in a project that was main problem !!!!!! now kept all files in a project and it worked !!!!!!

Comment: @AdamS thanks you very much for taking your time and answering this question thank you very much you solved many problems of mine in a single answer.

Comment: @DevSolar I am using CodeBlocks but the files was not in a project that was main problem !!!!!! now kept all files in a project and it worked !!!!!!